# how to change server root in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Default server root in nginx is `/usr/share/nginx/html`. How do I change it to `/home/username/html`? I've tried to add this configuration in site-available but didn't work!

```
server {
        listen   80;
        root /home/username/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name mj.dev;
}
```

Comment: Have you linked it into sites-enabled?

Answer (score 0):

try restart your nginx server!

```
    nginx -s restart
```

if i still does work check weather you load the right configuration file.

use

```
    nginx -t
```

to check the syntax of your configuration file

Answer (score 0):

If

```
nginx -s restart
```

is not working, you should try

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

but normally it's enough, to reload the configuration file

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

you can also try to place the *nginx.conf* file right into */etc/nginx*
(in case, you haven't linked it correctly)